# Tomcat JPA PersistenceUnit JNDI Name

Tags: jpa, jndi, entitymanager, tomcat8, persistence-unit

I've developed a JPA project to be deployed into my Tomcat8 instance.

I need then to lookup my PersistenceUnit EntityManagerFactory by JNDI context lookup. I know that with JBoss Wildfly there is the possibility to use:

```
<property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name" value="java:/persistence/JNDIUnitNAME"/>
```

property which allows me to lookup the EntityManagerFactory by the standard JNDI lookup method.

```
InitialContext txt = new InitialContext();
EntityManagerFactory emf = (EntityManagerFactory)ctx.lookup("java:/persistence/JNDIUnitNAME");
```

Is there a similar property for Tomcat server?